# I want to find the number which act to 0 of Julia - I mean the nearest number of 0

Tags: julia, underflow

Why does this happen in Julia?

My input is

```
A = []
for i = 17:21
    t = 1/(10^(i))
    push!(A, t)
end
return(A)
```

And the output was:

```
5-element Array{Any,1}:
  1.0e-17
  1.0e-18
 -1.1838881245526248e-19
  1.2876178137472069e-19
  2.5800991659088344e-19
```

I observed that

```
A[3]>0
false
```

I want to find the number which act to 0 of Julia, but I found this and don’t understand.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this problem is when you have `i = 19`, note that then:

```
julia> 10^19
-8446744073709551616
```

and it is unrelated to floating point numbers, but is caused by `Int64` overflow.

Here is the code that will work as you expect. Either use `10.0` instead of `10` as `10.0` is a `Float64` value:

```
julia> A=[]
Any[]

julia> for i=17:21
       t=1/(10.0^(i))
       push!(A,t)
       end

julia> A
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 1.0e-17
 1.0e-18
 1.0e-19
 1.0e-20
 1.0e-21
```

or using high precision `BigInt` type that is created using `big(10)`

```
julia> A=[]
Any[]

julia> for i=17:21
       t=1/(big(10)^(i))
       push!(A,t)
       end

julia> A
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 9.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999967e-18
 9.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997e-19
 9.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997e-20
 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004e-20
 9.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999927e-22
```

You can find more discussion of this here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Overflow-behavior.

For example notice that (which you might find surprising not knowing about the overflow):

```
julia> x = typemin(Int64)
-9223372036854775808

julia> x^2
0

julia> y = typemax(Int64)
9223372036854775807

julia> y^2
1
```

Finally to find smallest positive `Float64` number use:

```
julia> nextfloat(0.0)
5.0e-324
```

or

```
julia> eps(0.0)
5.0e-324
```